# How do I grep multiple patterns from a pipe

Tags: shell, grep, regular-expression, quoting

I want to find three patterns in a list. I tried typing

```
$ pip3 list | grep -ei foo -ei bar -ei baz
```

but the shell throws a `broken pipe error` and a large `Traceback`.

How do I `grep` for multiple patterns passed from a list that is piped to `grep`?

Comment: That should probably be `grep -ie foo -e bar -e baz`, no? the expressions should follow the `-e`

Comment: @steeldriver can you clarify? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Try `pip3 list | grep -ei` - you're asking `grep` to find all lines matching `i`

Comment: Your __1st__ comment worked but your __2nd__ didn't. Very strange, I get another broken pipe error and a very large Traceback for `grep -ei` but `grep -ie` works like the other answers below.

Comment: That was my point - the order of the `i` and `e` matters (because `i` is just a switch, whereas `e` expects an argument)

Comment: Ahh now its clear why `-e` must be last and also why `-i` is needed only once, while `-e` is needed for every pattern. Good answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
pip3 list | grep -Ei 'foo|bar|baz'
```

Here is a real life example from my Arch server:

```
pip3 list | grep -Ei 'ufw|set'
setuptools 40.0.0 
ufw        0.35
```

---

OS and `grep` info:

```
uname -a
Linux archlinux 4.16.6-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr 30 12:30:03 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux

grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 3.1
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and others, see <http://git.sv.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/AUTHORS>.
```

Comment: Note that `egrep` is deprecated in favor of `grep -E`, for what it's worth.

Comment: @multithr3at3d: Depends on the system.  Solaris for example does not have a `grep -E` and therefore your __only__ option _is_ `egrep`.  Parenthesis are not required though.

Comment: @multithr3at3d Umm... Ok. That was news to me. I have used `egrep` forever, and still do.

Comment: @Jesse_b you're right, my comment is in reference to GNU `grep`. @maulinglawns it still works for historical compatibility

Comment: can confirm `egrep` and `grep -E` both work.

Comment: @Jesse_b really? Could that be a particularly old version of Solaris, or is that the norm? `-E` is specified by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/grep.html) and even the POSIX specs suggest that `egrep` is historical.

Comment: @terdon: At least up to v9

Comment: @maulinglawns is it important that the patterns are protected by single quotations or would double quotations suffice?

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia Use single quotes for static strings. only use double quotes if you need the shell to expand anything in the strings, like in `-e "something$myvar"`, where you may want it to substitute the value of `$myvar`. If the pattern contains any `$` that _shouldn't_ be expanded by the shell, these need to be escaped as `\$` if you're using double quotes.

Comment: Thank you @terdon and @multithr3at3d for enlightening me on `grep -E` vs `egrep`. I will try to refrain from the latter in the future, but it will take some getting used to!

Comment: thanks @Kusalananda I will keep that in mind, I thought may be it was needed to prevent the `|` from expanding.

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia The pipe symbol is not special in any way inside a quoted string of any type.

Answer (score 8):

The reason

```
grep -ei foo -ei bar -ei baz
```

does not work is because the semantics for the `-e` option is `-e PATTERN`, as in

```
grep -i -e foo -e bar -e baz
```

... which is what the command should have looked like. The `-i` option (for case insensitive matching) will only need to be specified once and will affect all patterns.

With `-ei foo` you ask `grep` to look for the pattern `i` in the file `foo`.

The "broken pipe" error comes from `pip3` trying to write to the end of a dead pipe.  The pipe is dead because `grep` could not find the files `foo`, `bar` or `baz`, and terminated (with three "file not found" errors).  The traceback is from `pip3` which is a Python program (so it tells you exactly where in the Python code the fault happened on its side).

Comment: Really good explanation, thanks. Related question: if `-ei foo` is asking `grep` to look for the pattern `i` in the file `foo` then why doesn't it just return a pattern or file not found error, instead of filling up my screen with a Traceback for a broken pipe error.

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia `grep` should have given you a "file not found" error (look at the top, before the traceback). Python programs often give tracebacks on errors.  Note that it's `pip3` that gives you the traceback, not `grep`.  It does that because you've asked to write to a pipe that nobody is listening at the other end of (`grep` already died because it couldn't open the files you told it to look in).

Comment: Your right, I didn't see the `grep: foo: No such file or directory` error before because it was lost in the sea of information, I can't see the others, may be they are there somewhere. Thanks for imparting the knowledge. One more thing, is this Traceback saved anywhere so I know if I have to delete it or is it just passed to stdoutput only?

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia The traceback from `pip3` is sent to its standard error stream. It is not saved anywhere on file by default.